# Android WifiLock is not working correctly on Android

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi, wifimanager

I'm trying to lock wifi after connected to an access point but device switch to another network after 2 to 3 minutes.
Here is how I'm trying to do.

```
        private static final String TAG = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ":WAKE_LOCK_TAG";
    public MyWifiManager(){
        mWifiLock = ((WifiManager) App.getContext().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE)).createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL_HIGH_PERF ,"MyWifiManager:mWifiLock");
        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) App.getContext().getSystemService(App.getContext().POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, TAG)
    }


    public void acquireWifiLock(){
        if (mWifiLock != null && !mWifiLock.isHeld()){
            mWifiLock.acquire();
        }
    }

    public void releaseWifiLock() {
        if( mWifiLock != null && mWifiLock.isHeld() ){
            mWifiLock.release();
        }
    }   

    public void acquireWakeLock(){
        if (wakeLock != null && !wakeLock.isHeld()){
            wakeLock.acquire();
        }
    }

    public void releaseWakeLock() {
        if( wakeLock != null && wakeLock.isHeld() ){
            wakeLock.release();
        }
    }
```

Here is my manifest file

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE " />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: why are you repeating permissions?

Comment: Oh! this is the only reason to not work of WifiLock?

Comment: not that for your problem

Answer (score 1):

WifiLock has a different purpose. It is used for keeping the Wi-Fi radio on and is not meant for locking to a particular network.

Ref: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.WifiLock

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiLock = wm.createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL_HIGH_PERF , "MyWifiLock");
        wifiLock.acquire();
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyWakeLock");
        wakeLock.acquire();
```

And release the locks in `onDestroy` method:

```
if (wakeLock != null) {
            if (wakeLock.isHeld()) {
                wakeLock.release();
            }
        }
        if (wifiLock != null) {
            if (wifiLock.isHeld()) {
                wifiLock.release();
            }
        }
```

Comment: That's my mistake, I didn't add code of wake lock of PowerManager in the description. Now That's updated.